# MySQL : cumulative count with other data gives wrong output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a single table to get cumulative sales by date and also trying add total traffic data(just value) to the same table. Although my cumulative count is perfect, the total_traffic count totally wrong.

If I run total traffic as a seperate query the answer is perfect. Not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
select a.date, (@cumulative := @cumulative + a.sales) AS cumulative, "" as total_traffic 
FROM  
(select date, sales  
 from table1
 group by date  
 order by date) AS a, (SELECT @cumulative:=0) AS n
UNION
select "" as date, "" as cumulative, sum(traffic) as total_traffic from table2
```

Comment: try `UNION ALL` to retain all rows. Is `date` really a string column? And don't you have cumulative `sales` in the first query but then `traffic` in your total row?

Comment: union all does not make a diff. yes the date is a string. The idea is to get the cumulative sales but just the total traffic in one table

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Explain how the value is wrong.